# Which invoices are greater than $300, that have been paid prior to 7/15/2008 and are either TermsID 2 or 3

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got this far from my homework question, but I am little confused how the code will work for paid prior for date and termsID 2 or 3?

Write a SELECT statement that returns VendorID, InvoiceNumber, InvoiceDate, InvoiceTotal, TermsID and PaymentDate that answers the following question: Which invoices are greater than $300, that have been paid prior to 7/15/2008 and are either TermsID 2 or 3? (18 records will be returned)

Select VendorID, invoiceNumber, InvoiceDate, InvoiceTotal, TermsID, PaymentDate
From invoices
Where invoices > 300 and

Comment: I'd suggest working on the parts of the WHERE clause separately (Invoices > 300 and then date prior to 7/15/2008 and then Types 2 or 3).  Once you get the parts working as they should then you can figure out the ands and ors to put them together.

Comment: Include a schema with you question, also don't ask homework help questions

Answer (score 0):

Here are some pointers:

If your column for paid date is (as it should be) a date, you can structure a predicate that looks for things before a date using the `<` operator jsut as you would with a number. Later dates are greater:

```
--find all people born before 1970 jan 01
SELECT * FROM person WHERE birthdate < '1970-01-01'
```

Pass your date for comparison as a string (surrounded by `'`) in yyyy-MM-dd format. The db will convert the string to a date and run the comparison numerically

---

Use the IN operator when you want to look for a column being in a set of terms:

```
SELECT * FROM person WHERE jobrole IN ('manager', 'developer', 'support')

SELECT * FROM creature WHERE numberoflegs IN (2,4,6)
```

IN works like:

```
SELECT * FROM creature WHERE numberoflegs =2 OR numberoflegs = 4 OR numberoflegs = 6
```

---

Always, always include brackets when mixing AND and OR, to make it clear to the DB and to other people reading your code, what is to be combined in which way

```
--for this...
SELECT * FROM person WHERE name = 'john' and age = 32 or city = 'paris'

--which of these is it? very different things!
SELECT * FROM person WHERE (name = 'john' and age = 32) or city = 'paris'
SELECT * FROM person WHERE name = 'john' and (age = 32 or city = 'paris')
```